# What is "lifecycle features" in React hooks?

Tags: react-hooks

While learning hooks came across the definition

> Hooks are functions that let you “hook into” React state and lifecycle
> features from function components

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

but nowhere it's mentioned what is `lifecycle features` ?

Couldn't find exact answer to this query googling as well

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle in React is talking about a component getting created, updated, and destroyed, aka its "lifecycle". Before hooks were a thing and components were primarily class-based (eg `extends React.Component`), components had lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate`. When a component mounted to the DOM, `componentDidMount` would fire, when the component re-rendered due to a state or prop change, `componentDidUpdate` would fire, etc. As such, state is also closely tied to this discussion, and previously `setState()` is how a component would update its state and cause a component re-render.

Functional components have since become the more modern option for creating components, but since functions can't hold their own properties like a class can, hooks were introduced, which allow a function component to reference specific state with `useState()` or "hook" into the component lifecycle with `useEffect()`.

You can read more about lifecycle on React's State and Lifecycle page: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

You can also check out how hooks are able to replace a class component's state and lifecycle methods by looking at the useEffect page and useState page in the React docs which show implementations of the same component in both a class-based and function-based component: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html